# Why don't these countable nouns have articles in this sentence?

Tags: articles, zero-article, countable-nouns

Why exactly don't "header" and "body" need articles in the following sentence ([as per this answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/272623/6327))?

> We've improved the visual separation between header and body in classes with multiline headers.

What are the rules behind this? Don't such nouns always require a determiner?

Answer (score 1):

This is simply an elided form of

> We've improved the visual separation between the header and the body in classes with multiline headers.

Since an indefinite article would not make sense, the definite article can safely be omitted and understood, and people often do so. Each class has exactly one header and one footer, so there is no misunderstanding.